# Favor format over String#% rubocop

Tags: ruby, rubocop

```
request_url ||= URI_FORMATS[:home_page] % {
          base_uri:     AppConfig.test_api['base_url'],
          end_point:    AppConfig.test_api['end_points']['home_page'],
          client_id:    AppConfig.test_api['client_id'],
        }
```

I am getting Favor format over String#% rubocop error for this.
Any idea how to resolve this. I just gone through the cause of the error here

```
https://quynhcodes.wordpress.com/2017/03/29/string-interpolation-in-ruby/
```

But I am not using any string interpolation here.

So how can we solve this issue.?

Answer (score 13):

First of all, this is not about string interpolation, but about string formatting. The [RuboCop Ruby style guide](https://rubystyle.guide/#sprintf) says:

> Favor the use of `sprintf` and its alias `format` over the fairly cryptic `String#%` method.

This would mean changing

```
request_url ||= URI_FORMATS[:home_page] % {
  base_uri:  AppConfig.test_api['base_url'],
  end_point: AppConfig.test_api['end_points']['home_page'],
  client_id: AppConfig.test_api['client_id'],
}
```

to

```
request_url ||= format(
  URI_FORMATS[:home_page],
  base_uri:  AppConfig.test_api['base_url'],
  end_point: AppConfig.test_api['end_points']['home_page'],
  client_id: AppConfig.test_api['client_id'],
)
```